# Why are fs.dirent.isSymbolicLink() results diffenent to stats.isSymbolicLink() in windows Node.js?

Tags: node.js, symlink

I have some files and dirs on windows. use `ls` in `PowerShell` it returns:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----l         2021/7/29     17:29                Saved Pictures
-a---l         2021/5/12     15:39         421888 LICEcap1.26.exe
```

Because of the `l` in `Mode`, they look like a symbolic link.

When I call `isSymblickLink()` of `Dirent` returned by `fs.readdirSync(filename, {withFileTypes: true})`, it also returns **`true`**

But, When I use `fs.lstat(filename)` and then `stat.isSymblickLink()`, it returns **`false`**

So why are `fs.dirent.isSymbolicLink()` results diffenent to `fs.stats.isSymbolicLink()`?

Is this normal or a bug of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal for Windows, Linux, etc. You can check [fs | nodejs-16](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html) document for the returned value of `fs.readdirSync`, `fs.statSync` and `fs.lstatSync`.

> For symlink: `readdir` = `lstat` != `stat`
> For others:  `readdir` = `lstat` = `stat`

`lstat` is equivalent to `stat` **unless** `path` refers to a **symbolic link**, in which case **the link itself** is stat-ed, not the file that it refers to. And the `readdir` with `withFileTypes=true` returns the stat-ed information **same as** `lstat`, because the `Dirent` of nodejs represents a directory entry, which can be either a file, dir, symlink or others (block...). The symlink `Dirent` itself is stat-ed, not the file or sub directory that it refers to.

Let's make an example,

```
a/      (parent dir)
|- b/   (directory)     <----
|  \- c (file)          <---|---
|                           |  |
|- d/   (symlink to b/) -----  |
|- e    (file)                 |
\- f    (symlink to c)  --------
```

You can run instrctions in nodejs cli.

```js
// readdir
console.log(fs.readdirSync('.', {withFileTypes: true}).map(e =>
  `${e.name}\t${e.isFile()}\t${e.isDirectory()}\t${e.isSymbolicLink()}`
).join('\n'))

// stat
console.log(fs.readdirSync('.').map(n => { let e = fs.statSync(n);
  return `${n}\t${e.isFile()}\t${e.isDirectory()}\t${e.isSymbolicLink()}`
}).join('\n'))

// lstat
console.log(fs.readdirSync('.').map(n => { let e = fs.lstatSync(n);
  return `${n}\t${e.isFile()}\t${e.isDirectory()}\t${e.isSymbolicLink()}`
}).join('\n'))
```

Output of `readdir` and `lstat` are:

```
b       false   true    false // dir
d       false   false   true  // symlink to dir
e       true    false   false // file
f       false   false   true  // symlink to file
```

Output of `stat` are:

```
b       false   true    false // dir
d       false   true    false // dir (symlink)
e       true    false   false // file
f       true    false   false // file (symlink)
```

Comment: While this looks right, it doesn't answer the question. The OP is comparing `Dirent` to `fs.lstat`, which *should* be the same. There's no mention of `fs.stat`.

Comment: `Dirent`s represent children of a directory, so appling `fs.stat` to `fs.readdir`'s result will return the `Dirent`'s information. `fs.lstat` extends the function of `fs.stat`, it will convert a symbolic link `Dirent` to the dir it pointed to, so `fs.lstat` should not be the same as looking up `Dirent` itself.

Comment: Possibly a typo but I think you have that comment backwards (your answer is correct). `fs.stat` dereferences (follows) symlinks, so will return information about the target of the symlink. `fs.lstat` returns information about the link itself, which is what `fs.readdir` on the parent directory should do as well.

In the OP's case, the result of `fs.lstat` is not consistent with the `Dirent`. That looks like a bug to me.